# Assigning permission to C++ program

Tags: permissions, c++

I'm trying to run a program in C++ compiladom in Ubuntu, but is giving permission denied. I tried chmod 755 file but does not work. How do I solve this?

Comment: Could you please provide more details like whether you were using it in command line or IDE... and if possible the full output/error

Comment: Sounds like the program may be using other files as well, files for which you don't have the rights.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running the program as a normal user? are you able to run the program using sudo?

try doing

```
chmod +x programname
```

Comment: Don't just blindly use sudo. Use sudo when you need to do something as root (i.e. an administrative operation).

Comment: Note that I have /dev/sda6 on /media/HD type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks) e a opção showexec está me impedindo de executar os binarios.